# How to adjust or find the optimal drive belt tightness?

Tags: drive-belt

I need to change my Toyota Matrix 2012 alternator.

The installation is not complicated, except I need to lose the drive belt and tighten it again.

Is there any guideline on how to find the optimal tightness for the drive belt?

Is the tightness can be roughly checked by hand, or it has to be very precise?

**Update 1:**

*I think * the tightness can be adjusted by the bolt pointed in this picture:

[image]

Comment: Most cars today use a serpentine-type belt with a tensioner.  Are you sure you can even tighten this one?

Comment: As commented ; a properly working tensioner will control the tension.

Comment: jwh20 and  @blacksmith37, Please see the update and the picture I added. Is my underestanding correct?

Comment: That is an adjuster, I have not seen one with a serpentine belt . Maybe it is used for a rough adjustment to get the tensioner to a proper position. Those few that I have done released the tensioner , install belt, then put the tensioner to its normal position.  Can you loosen the tensioner ?

Comment: @blacksmith37, I am not very technical, but I saw people in youtube use the adjuster to losen the belt. Here is an example for my car - video in low light, but it shoud ne accurate.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjUc9gCMHiY